# Why dollar variable has no ancestors even in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, object

In Ruby, **everything is an object**. I interpreted it as everything is inherited from the `BasicObject` and has ancestors.

But I found dollar variable (`$!`, `$1`) doesn't have ancestors.

They don't response to the `ancestor` method which is defined on `BasicObject`.

Comment: In Ruby, variables do not have a class, and are not inherently an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `ancestor` method in Ruby's core, I'm assuming you mean `ancestors`. [`ancestors` is defined in `Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-ancestors), and is callable on a module or class object, *not* instances of them.

```
$1.ancestors
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `ancestors' for nil:NilClass
#     from (irb):4
#     from /Users/amarshall/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

$1.class.ancestors
#=> [NilClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

This is not unique to global variables, and applies to all objects and variable types.

It's important to note that `Object.methods` is not the same as `Object.new.methods`:

```
Object.methods.include? :ancestors       #=> true
Object.new.methods.include? :ancestors   #=> false
```

This is because an object's *class* has ancestors, not the object itself (unless the object is in fact a class/module).

Answer (score 1):

Actually `ancestors` is defined in the `Module` class. Only objects that are instance of Module or Class (like `BasicObject`) has this method. So you can't call `"something".ancestors`, but you can do `String.ancestors` or `"something".class.ancestors`. The same is valid for 'dollar' variables (`$!.class.ancestors`).